What's my options for a 'basic' single slot/'modern' basic GPU?
TLDR: I need a cheap, broadly linux and windows compatible GPU that'll fit into a single slot.
I've currently been building/working on a system I intend to use as a home server box. Its a chinese MATX motherboard that has a xeon processor. Hardware specs as per speccy are as below

        CPU
            Intel Xeon E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz 39 °C
            Broadwell-E/EP 14nm Technology
        RAM
            96.0GB DDR4 @ 1197MHz (17-17-17-39)
        Motherboard
            INTEL MATX-CS612 (SOCKET 0) 27 °C
        Graphics
            Generic Non-PnP Monitor (3840x2160@32Hz)
            ASPEED Technology ASPEED Graphics Family(WDDM) (ASPEED Technology)
        Storage
            931GB Crucial CT1000P3PSSD8 (Unknown (SSD))
        Optical Drives
            No optical disk drives detected
        Audio

At the moment, I'm running video through the built in AST2400 - a on board video adaptor with a whopping 16mb of video ram, and while it is suprisingly good enough to work, on this board it is VGA only, and I need to run an adaptor. My primary goal here is to get HDMI support as cheaply and compactly as possible
One of my other  issues with this build is I am deeply space constrained.

Ideally, I'd like to use the right most slot and not 'lose' the other slots. I don't have space for a vertical mount, and while my current PSU will support a better video card (it used to power a 980TI) , I'd ideally prefer a self powered card which dosen't need additional power past the PCIe slot.
An additional wrinkle is - I'd like current driver support for windows 10 if possible and good linux support out of the box. This machine does VT-D so I may choose to pass through video in some circumstances.  I do believe this platform also does r-bar if necessary.
I won't be gaming much on this, so I'm not looking powerful I'm looking for a relatively basic card that'll fit into a tight space, and have good driver support.
What would be my options here?

Plenty of options, particularly from the workstation market on the AMD side. What are your needs though in terms of actual performance though? Something like a WX 4100/5100/7100 would probably be a good choice. It also looks like you could put a dual-slot card in the bottom slot without blocking anything, and dual-slot consumer cards are typically considerably cheaper than their single-slot counterparts. Even with the bandwidth constraints of 8x, I think you'd see more performance/$.

I can't put in a dual slot card in that slot - x8 aside, there's some unusual design on the case, and I had to trim down the slot cover on the 'empty' slot for it to go in.  Any dual slot option means 'losing' a usable slot. I'm planning on putting a fan modded x8 10 gig nic there eventually, but am still working out the details on that.  Its mainly going to be a VM host/CLI build/test/experimentation box so - the desire for modern drivers and interfaces aside, I'd be quite happy with a potato.  I'm literally running it now with a 16mb interface so most things would be an improvement

AMD Radeon RX 550 (OEM) - ≈$25


GCN 4-based card (Polaris 12); reasonably modern, but cheap and available.
Supported in Linux via the in-tree amdgpu kernel driver, as well as the userspace Mesa and AMDVLK drivers (if you don't know what that means, don't worry about it, but you can look at this diagram here if you want.)
Still actively supported and maintained in current Windows drivers, unlike GCN 3/2/1-based cards. AMD is winding down updates for this generation, and will probably stop providing driver updates in the next couple years, but it's not like your card will magically stop working at that time.
Very cheap and very low power.
Low-profile cards are available, if you ever opt to move to an even tinier case.

